# jQuery validationEngine Ajax validation for form fields needs callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validation-engine

If you are using jQuery ValidationEngine to validate a form with AJAX you direct handling of the before and after with callbacks:

```
jQuery("#testForm").validationEngine('attach', 
{
    promptPosition : "bottomLeft", 
    validationEventTrigger : "submit", 
    ajaxFormValidation: true,
    onBeforeAjaxFormValidation: function() {
        alert('before');
    },
    onAjaxFormComplete : function(status, form, errors, options) {
        alert('after');
    }
});
```

That's cool and all, but I just want to validate an individual field (in this case, the text input "**input[name='name']**"):

```html
<script>
$("#testBtn").click(function() {
    var resp = $("#testForm").validationEngine("validate");
});
</script>
<form onsubmit="return false;" 
    onclick="$('#testForm').validationEngine('hide')" 
    name="testForm" 
    id="testForm" 
    action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="providerId" value="0" />
    <input name="name" value="Default Provider" class="validate[required, ajax[checkProviderNameExists]]" />
    <button id="testBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When the submit button is clicked, jQuery ValidationEngine will submit the checkProviderNameExists request to the server and display the correct/incorrect prompt depending on the result. If validation passes, however, I want to be able to submit the form at that point. Is this possible? **Basically I need a callback function for field validation so I can take appropriate action depending on if the form validates or not.**

For the sake of completeness here is my implemenation of the custom ajax validator:

```
"checkProviderNameExists" : {
    "url": "/settings/checkprovidernameexists",
    "extraDataDynamic": "providerId",
    "alertText": "* This provider name already exists",
    "alertTextLoad": "Checking name..."
}
```

Comment: Found the following URL: http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/using-form-ajax-validation-with-the-jquery-validation-engine-plugin/ and it seems to indicate that what I want is not possible.

"The inline validation is not called on submit. The inline ajax validation is meant to interact with your users directly, you will have to verify the information on submit too"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting an AJAX validator on an individual field only executes at runtime. To accomplish what I wanted, I had to use ajax to validate the entire form, and in that particular ajax handler do validation on the individual fields.

Comment: Hello @IcedDante if possible can you help me? I've same issue and I am not able to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution that i Found is

```
function validateUserName(field, rules, i, options){
if($('#mName').val()){
    var isValidName = true;
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/yourroute/"+$('#mName').val(), 
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            success: function(result){
                isValidName =  (result == 1) ? false : true;
            },
            async: false
        });
    if(isValidName==false){
        console.log("False");
        return 'Name is already taken';
    }
}
```

}

and in html

```
data-validation-engine="validate[required,funcCall[validateUserName]"
```

Answer (score 0):

similar to previous solution

```
<input id='r_email' name="r_email" type="email" class="validate[required,custom[email],funcCall[validate_email]]" placeholder="Please enter your valid email address">


<script>
  function validate_email(field, rules, i, options) {       
    response = $.ajax({
        url: '/php/chkEmail.php?pr_email=' + $('#r_email').val(), 
        type: 'GET',
        async: false
    }).responseText;
    
    if (response != 'available') 
        return "email is taken. Please try different email";        
}
</script>
```